# Away3D click listener doesn't work with all the cube, only its center

Tags: actionscript-3, 3d, listener, away3d

I am trying to add a click listener to a cube in Away3D. This works... partially. Seems like the click works only with the center of the cube's face. I have no idea why this is so because it should be taking the bounding box (which, of course, is all the cube). So if I click somewhere "near" the edge of the cube, nothing happens.

The code is rather simple:

```
cube = new Mesh(new CubeGeometry(400, 400, 400, 1, 1, 1, false));
cube.mouseEnabled = true;
cube.addEventListener(MouseEvent3D.CLICK, cubeClickHandler);
var t:Trident = new Trident();
cube.addChild(t);
scene.addChild(cube);

...

private function cubeClickHandler(event:MouseEvent3D):void {
    navigateToURL(new URLRequest("http://www.google.com"));

}
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong and how to resolve it? Thanks a lot!

[Example here](http://tests.pixelhood.com/cube/)

Answer (score 0):

Here some suggestions:

- have you tried to rotate the camera?
- have you tried without the trident?(it could have a big BB and occlude)
- have you tried with some other picking method?

  ```
  cube.pickingCollider = PickingColliderType.AS3_BEST_HIT
  ```
- It's possible that the framerate in the example (1FPS) could interfere, try to set it at least at 10FPS